# Is it possible to add conditions to a MAX() call in an aggregated query?

Tags: mysql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

### Background

My typical use case:

```
# Table

id     category    dataUID
---------------------------
0         A        (NULL)
1         B        (NULL)
2         C        text1
3         C        text1
4         D        text2
5         D        text3

# Query

SELECT MAX(`id`) AS `id` FROM `table`
GROUP BY `category`
```

This is fine; it will strip out any "duplicate categories" in the recordset that's being worked on, giving me the "highest" ID for each category.

I can then go on use this ID to pull out all the data again:

```
# Query

SELECT * FROM `table` JOIN (
   SELECT MAX(`id`) AS `id` FROM `table`
   GROUP BY `category`
) _ USING(`id`)

# Result

id     category    dataUID
---------------------------
0         A        (NULL)
1         B        (NULL)
3         C        text1
5         D        text3
```

Note that this is *not* the same as:

```
SELECT MAX(`id`) AS `id`, `category`, `dataUID` FROM `table`
GROUP BY `category`
```

Per [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html):

> In standard SQL, a query that includes a GROUP BY clause cannot refer
>   to nonaggregated columns in the select list that are not named in the
>   GROUP BY clause. For example, this query is illegal in standard SQL
>   because the name column in the select list does not appear in the
>   GROUP BY:
>
> ```
> SELECT o.custid, c.name, MAX(o.payment)   FROM orders AS o, customers
> AS c   WHERE o.custid = c.custid   GROUP BY o.custid;
> ```
>
> For the query to be legal, the name column must be omitted from the
>   select list or named in the GROUP BY clause.
>
> **MySQL extends the use of GROUP BY so that the select list can refer to
>   nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY clause.** This means
>   that the preceding query is legal in MySQL. You can use this feature
>   to get better performance by avoiding unnecessary column sorting and
>   grouping. **However, this is useful primarily when all values in each
>   nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are the same for each
>   group.**
>
> [..]
>
> **This extension assumes that the nongrouped columns will have the same group-wise values. Otherwise, the result is indeterminate.**

So I'd get an unspecified value for `dataUID` — as an example, either `text2` *or* `text3` for result with `id` `5`.

This is actually a problem for other fields in my real case; as it happens, for the `dataUID` column specifically, generally I don't really care *which* value I get.

---

### Problem

However!

If any of the rows for a given `category` has a `NULL` `dataUID`, and at least one other row has a non-`NULL` `dataUID`, I'd like `MAX` to ignore the `NULL` ones.

So:

```
id     category    dataUID
---------------------------
4         D        text2
5         D        (NULL)
```

At present, since I pick out the row with the maximum ID, I get:

```
5         D        (NULL)
```

But, because the `dataUID` is `NULL`, instead I want:

```
4         D        text2
```

**How can I get this? How can I add conditional logic to the use of aggregate `MAX`?**

---

I thought of maybe handing `MAX` a tuple and pulling the `id` out from it afterwards:

```
GET_SECOND_PART_SOMEHOW(MAX((IF(`dataUID` NOT NULL, 1, 0), `id`))) AS `id`
```

But I don't think `MAX` will accept arbitrary expressions like that, let alone tuples, and I don't know how I'd retrieve the second part of the tuple after-the-fact.

Comment: And if all rows for a category have `dataUID NULL`, what should happen?

Comment: @ypercube: Fall-back to sorting by ID. I just want to prioritise any `dataUID`-present rows that _do_ exist within a group, when doing the sorting.

Comment: @ajreal: Ta. I couldn't find an alternative to the obviously-inappropriate `max` tag ;)

Comment: @ajreal: Yes, I suppose [that's true](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/6217672/revisions) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

slight tweak to [@ypercube's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8538549/73226). To get the `id`s you can use

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(CASE
                      WHEN dataUID IS NOT NULL THEN id
                    END), MAX(id)) AS id
FROM   table
GROUP  BY category
```

And then plug that into a `join`

Comment: That seems to yield the same results as my solution, though I can't for the life of me figure out how :D

Comment: Nice. Simple and probably much faster than my twisted final version.

Answer (score 2):

This was easier than I thought, in the end, because it turns out MySQL *will* accept an arbitrary expression inside `MAX`.

I can get the ordering I want by injecting a leading character into `id` to serve as an ordering hint:

```
SUBSTRING(MAX(IF (`dataUID` IS NULL, CONCAT('a',`id`), CONCAT('b',`id`))) FROM 2)
```

---

Walk-through:

```
id     category    dataUID    IF (`dataUID` IS NULL, CONCAT('a',`id`), CONCAT('b',`id`)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0         A        (NULL)                             a0
1         B        (NULL)                             a1
2         C        text1                              b2
3         C        text1                              b3
4         D        text2                              b4
5         D        (NULL)                             a5
```

So:

```
SELECT
   `category`, MAX(IF (`dataUID` IS NULL, CONCAT('a',`id`), CONCAT('b',`id`)) AS `max_id_with_hint`
FROM `table`
GROUP BY `category`

category   max_id_with_hint
------------------------------
A          a0
B          a1
C          b3
D          b4
```

It's then a simple matter to chop the ordering hint off again.

Thanks in particular to @JlStone for setting me, via `COALESCE`, on the path to embedding expressions inside the call to `MAX` and directly manipulating the values supplied to `MAX`.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can remember you can use [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) inside of grouping statements. For example.

```
SELECT MAX(COALESCE(`id`,1)) ...
```

---

hm seems I read to quickly the first time. I think maybe you want something like this?

```
SELECT * FROM `table` JOIN (
   SELECT MAX(`id`) AS `id` FROM `table`
   WHERE `dataUID` IS NOT NULL
   GROUP BY `category`
) _ USING(`id`)
```

or perhaps

```
SELECT MAX(`id`) AS `id`, 
  COALESCE (`dataUID`, 0) as `dataUID`
FROM `table`
GROUP BY `category`
```

Comment: OK, so I'd write `COALESCE(\`dataUID\`, \`id\`)`, but then I'll get the `dataUID` for some rows and the `id` for others.. applying `MAX` to that will yield surprising results.

Comment: `MAX(COALESCE(IF (\`dataUID\` IS NOT NULL, CONCAT('b',\`id\`), NULL), CONCAT('a',\`id\`)))` might do what I want. I always get `id` in the result, but I also get the "`dataUID` before non-`dataUID`" ordering information; I can strip that ordering character later... hmm..

Comment: @Tomalak You mean something like `MAX(IF (\`dataUID\` IS NULL, -1, \`id\`)) AS \`id\``?

Comment: @JlStone: Going in that direction. I think I figured it out now. Thanks for your tips!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table AS t
  JOIN
  ( SELECT DISTINCT category
    FROM table
  ) AS tdc
  ON t.id = 
  COALESCE(
    ( SELECT MAX(id) AS id 
      FROM table 
      WHERE category = tdc.category
        AND dataUID IS NOT NULL
    ) 
  , ( SELECT MAX(id) AS id 
      FROM table 
      WHERE category = tdc.category
        AND dataUID IS NULL
    ) 
  )
```

Comment: No, because then I won't get any results at all for category `A` or `B`! From q: "If any of the rows for a given category has a NULL dataUID, and _at least one other row has a non-NULL dataUID_, I'd like MAX to ignore the NULL ones." If none of the rows has a non-NULL dataUID, I want to fall back to the ID ordering.

Comment: Yep, I think that'll do it. Martin's requires a much more localised alteration to my existing queries, and I find it _slightly_ easier to follow, so that's what I'll be going for. But still, thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from t1
join (
  select max(id) as id,
    max(if(dataGUID is NULL, NULL, id)) as fallbackid,
    category
  from t1 group by category) as ids
on if(ids.id = fallbackid or fallbackid is null, id, fallbackid) = t1.id;
```

Comment: I believe that should also do the job. Thanks!

Comment: Is `ids.id = fallbackid or ` redundant?

Comment: @Tomalak, it is not, it is required when only the max id has null for the dataGUID.

Comment: But surely if `ids.id = fallbackid` then either of the two operands can be used since, as discovered by the condition, they're equivalent?

Comment: @Tomalak, the condition fallbackid is null is true only when all dataguids are null, there should be an additional condition

Comment: @Tomalak, basically, 'ON LEAST(ids.id, fallbackid) = t1.id' would express the same idea

Answer (score -1):

you need clause OVER

```
SELECT id, category,dataUID 
FROM
 (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY id desc, dataUID desc ) rn, 
    id, category,dataUID FROM table 
 ) q
WHERE rn=1
```

Consider that sorting by desc moves null values at last.

Comment: `OVER` is from Oracle, isn't it? I'm not aware that MySQL supports it.

Comment: oops my fault, I didn't noticed MySQL. Actually it is MS SQL.